# Rails: link_to not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, link-to, ruby-on-rails-4.2, embedded-ruby

I made a ruby on rails app called LearnPython. I have a link_to in 1 of them that is not showing up. I will put in a few files so that you can help me. Sorry if this is a really simple error that could be solved by you in 2 seconds.

`app/views/learn/hub.html.erb`

```
<h1>Time to LearnPython!!!</h1>
<%= link_to "Lesson 1: Variables", lesson1_path %>
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'welcome#index'

    get 'signup' => 'users#new'
    resources :users

    get '/learn/' => 'learn#hub'
    get '/learn/1' => 'learn#var', as: :lesson1

    get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create'

    get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

`app/controllers/learn_controller.rb`

```
class LearnController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_user

    def hub
    end

    def var
    end
end
```

If you want me to put in more files, I will.

Comment: try the answer below

Answer (score 2):

On your view

```
<h1>Time to LearnPython!!!</h1>
<%= link_to "Lesson 1: Variables", lesson1_path %>
```

to show the link

Answer (score 0):

The above link looks totally fine. Please check out the style sheet, may be some style (display: none;) might have hidden your link. Also check the DOM to make sure whether link_to is being rendered properly or not. Thanks